Book recommendation on X-ray diffraction
I am a mathematician with just high-school level of physics  knowledge. I am studying the area of protein modelling and trying to understand how small angle x-ray scattering works. But I think my lack of knowledge on x-rays diffraction is hindering this.
Can someone recommend a book on the basics?

Could you maybe suggest some criteria on the book you want?

Two of the books in my collection:
"Principles of Protein X-ray Crystallography" by Jan Drenth
This book focuses on the application of X-ray diffraction to the study of proteins. It introduces protein crystallography. It shows how X-ray diffraction techniques are applied to biological macromolecules like proteins.  This sounds like it would be useful for what you are asking, though as OdinOblivion mentions you could suggest some criteria. We may be able to focus on other material.  I’ve checked the internet and it’s available with institution log-in, or to buy.
Elements of X-Ray Diffraction" by B.D. Cullity and S.R. Stock
I’ve included this as it is a classical text on x-ray diffraction.  It's not specifically orientated toward biological systems but covers the basics of diffraction /geometry of diffraction/diffraction from crystals. I checked the internet and it is available on “internet archives.”

"Elements of X-Ray Diffraction" was already the classic text more years ago than I'm willing to admit to myself. After it there was no need to write another introductory text.

For your convenience: Elements of X-Ray Diffraction, 1956 https://archive.org/details/elementsofxraydi030864mbp
